# How to prove limit by definition?

Tags: limits

How to prove this limit by definition $$\lim_{x,y\to0,0}\left(\frac{||(x,y)||^5}{x^4+y^4}\right)=0$$

I tried $$ \frac{||(x,y)||^5}{|x^4+y^4|} = \frac{(x^2+y^2)^2||(x,y)||}{|x^4+y^4|} = \frac{(x^4+y^4+2x^2y^2)||(x,y)||}{|x^4+y^4|}$$

But since $$ \frac{(x^4+y^4+2x^2y^2)}{|x^4+y^4|} \ge 1$$

I cant find a way to say $$||(x,y)|| \le \delta$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\|(x,y)\| \leq \sqrt  2 ( {x^{4}+y^{4}})^{1/4}$ so the given expression does not exceed $2^{5/2}(x^{4}+y^{4})^{1/5}$.

Answer (score 0):

In polar coordinates,

$$\frac{r^5}{r^4(\cos^4\theta+\sin^4\theta)}$$ and

$$\cos^4\theta+\sin^4\theta\ge\frac12.$$